# Value from .txt file wont be read into array in C program

Tags: c

I have a problem where i want to read each line to the struct array, but it wont read for example the "20 30" under "Alvedon" into 0 and 1 in the array, it reads the whole "20 30" to the array. How do i place 20 and 30 in different addresses in the array of the struct?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXANTAL 10000
#define MAXORD 20
#define PAKETSTORLEKAR 10
#define FILNAMNSTORLEK 20

struct lakemedel
{
    char namn[MAXORD];
    int antalForpackningar[PAKETSTORLEKAR];
    int saldo[PAKETSTORLEKAR];
};
typedef struct lakemedel Lakemedel;

void lasFil(Lakemedel lasLakemedelRegister[], int *pAntalLakemedel, char lasFilnamn[]);

int main()
{
    Lakemedel lakemedelRegister[MAXANTAL];
    char filnamn[FILNAMNSTORLEK];
    int antalLakemedel = 0;
    lasFil(lakemedelRegister, &antalLakemedel, filnamn);
    int val;

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("%s\n", lakemedelRegister[0].namn);
    printf("%s\n", lakemedelRegister[1].namn);
    printf("%s\n", lakemedelRegister[0].antalForpackningar[1]);

    return 0;
}

void lasFil(Lakemedel lasLakemedelRegister[], int *pAntalLakemedel, char lasFilnamn[])
{
    printf("Skriv in fil du vill anvanda: ");
    scanf(" %s", lasFilnamn);
    int i,f,s = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(lasFilnamn, "r");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        while(fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]\n", lasLakemedelRegister[i].namn)==1)
        {
            for(f=0; f<PAKETSTORLEKAR;f++)
            {
            fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", lasLakemedelRegister[i].antalForpackningar[f]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]\n", lasLakemedelRegister[i].saldo);
            (*pAntalLakemedel)++;
            i++;
        }
    fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Text file:

```
Alvedon
20 31
100 32
Ipren
10 41
30 42
```

Answer (score 0):

In `lasFil()` you never initialize the variable `i`, so when you use it as index in the array `lasLakemedelRegister` you end up with undefined behaviour.

The expression `int i,f,s=0;` will only initialize `s=0`.

Most sane compilers would haver warned you about this if you had turned on compiler warnings. Please always compile with `-Wall`

You are also using the wrong format specifier to read integers (use `%d`), and `fscanf()` expects a pointer in that case. `-Wall` should have warned you about this too.

The inner read loop looks messed up. To fix that you have to provide more info on how to interpret the data file.

Comment: And -Wextra is useful.  Here are a bunch of useful flags https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2017/09/useful-gcc-warning-options-not-enabled.html and https://kristerw.blogspot.com/2018/06/useful-gcc-address-sanitizer-checks-not.html

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't even notice! Ok, will keep that in mind:)

Answer (score 0):

everything you read is on string format, so it's up to you how to convert it to int or whatever you want. In this case, you need to split the string "20 31" to two strings "20" and "31" using function strtok and then use function atoi to convert strings to int 20 and 31.